# How can I get API keys for Walmart API ? Seems nothing is working

Tags: walmart-api

How can I get API keys for Walmart API ? Seems nothing is working. Can anybody share keys ? This is integral to our development. And no reply from Walmart. Page is not updated as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer service question for an off-site vendor. Contact Walmart Technical Support for assistance getting a key for your personal use. We can't provide  that assistance here, and keys cannot be shared. If someone gives you their key, they're liable for anything you do. We are not Walmart support for your personal account, as we have no access to your account. We're not Walmart.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your feedback. You are correct. However we have exhausted ways to reach Walmart customer support. We have emailed and used contact form unsuccessfully. We were under impression that this tag is moderated by Walmart team and they can update us (and other interested parties) on updated timeline.

Comment: Whether Walmart monitors the tag or not is irrelevant. The question is off-topic here. All questions posted here must meet this site's guidelines, and yours does not.

Comment: Question is not off topic. He has asked a question from the wider community to see if someone has run through the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign up for a new account here:  https://developer.walmartlabs.com/member/register

2022 updated link: https://developer.walmart.com/ under "How to get started" are instructions.